# run remote command to save debian package list

Tags: debian, backup, remote, command, dpkg

I'd like to backup the package list(dpkg) of some remote computers to a backup server: all of them running Debian. I already configured the rsa key to login remotely as root on the other computers without authentication. How can I run a command like "dpkg --get-selections > file"
on the remote computers to save the package list, so my backup server can copy those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh. For example: `ssh root@server -c "dpkg --get-selections" > localfile.txt`